# Chosen—Setting a Value from URL Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-chosen

A site redesign I've recently worked on incorporated Chosen into one of its search forms. The old version of the search allowed you to pass a variable through the URL to have a value pre-selected with the page loads. It was done using this:

```
function getUrlVars(){var vars={};
var parts=window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value){vars[key]=value;});
return vars;}

var type="";
type=getUrlVars()['type'];
if(typeof type!='undefined'){pro_type=type.split("%20").join(" ");
document.getElementById("product_type").value=pro_type;
productSearch();}
```

I'm trying to accomplish this with Chosen but I'm a bit lost. The `getElementById` tells me I can't call the method value of null. The only thing that's changed is the use of Chosen. Is there a way that I can fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you are trying to read "product_type" before it is rendered on the page.  You need to do it on dom ready, window.onload or put the JS after the element on the page.